# Waves argument in geeglm of geepack in R causes failure

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am trying to calculate a GEE-model in the R package "geepack". The response variable is proportional, coded as (Successes, Failures). The explanatory variables are Weight(cont), Rank(cont), ColonySize(cont) and Sex(factor). The data set contains temporal non-independence of observations because over a study period of 413 days repeated behavioral measurements of the same individuals where taken. This non-independence is reflected in a column specifying the AnimalID and the day of observation (Ndate). The data set is not very large and contains 1062 observations on 165 different individuals. The complete study period is 413 days (i.e. Ndate range:1-413).

```
gee1<-geeglm(wl~WeightScaled+Rank+ColonySize+Sex,
data=allsub, family=binomial, id=AnimalID, 
corstr="ar1")
```

The above model is calculated without difficulties and without noticeable delay. However, the observations are not regularly distributed over the study period (see the complete vector for Ndate below) which means the model output is not meaningful. When I include the waves argument in the model to correctly account for temporal auto-correlation R seems to get stuck or takes very long to calculate this model which should really not take so much time. What happens is that R-Gui displays "(not responding)" for more than 1 hour and the small circle (Win7) indicates that R is busy. The CPU-usage according to the task manager is mostly between 25-30%, sometimes up to 50%. So my question is: Did I make a mistake when specifying the "waves" function which cause R to hang itself or is it normal for this process to be computational very intense? (see an extract of the variable Ndate below)

Model including the waves argument:

```
gee1<-geeglm(wl~Weight+Rank+ColonySize+Sex,
data=allsub, family=binomial, id=AnimalID, 
corstr="ar1", waves=Ndate)
```

The second question is more fundamental with regards to this GEE and its autocorrelation structure: Is the model able to deal with this kind of temporal autocorrelation where repeated observations of one individual are typically 5-15 but time in between varies largely (sometimes only a few days, but sometimes up to 100 days or more). Textbook examples all look very different but as I see it the principle should be the same.

Thanks very much.

```
> allsub$Ndate
   [1] 169 169 169  43  43   5   5   5 267 267 267 267 162 162 162 162 162 256
  [19] 256 256 256 256 256 263 263 263 263 263 263 176 176 176 176 176 176 183
 [37] 183 183 183 183 183 190 190 190 190 190 190 190 196 196 196 196 196 196
 [55] 196 284 284 284 284 291 291 291 291 175 175 175 175 175 175 175 175 199
 [73] 199 199 199 199 199 199 186 186 186 186 186 186 189 189 189 189 189 189
 [91] 266 266 266 266 266 266 196 196 196 196 196 196 196 242 242 242 242 242
 [109] 242 207 207 207 207 207 210 210 210 210 210 245 245 245 245 245 245 302
 [127] 302 302 302 302 302 302 302 217 217 217 217 217 217 217 270 270 270 272
 [145] 272 272 291 291 291 220 220 220 220 220 220 220 238 238 238 238 238 238

 [757] 291 291 291 291 291 291 220 220 238 238 241 241 294 294 294 294 294 294
 [775] 303 303 303 263 263 263 263 263 263 263 263 263 263 316 316 309 304 304
 [793] 304 323 323  19  50  99  67  67  67  22  22  22  43  60 110 178 178 178
 [811]  33 115 115 115 115  96 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116  26
 [829]  26 122 122 122 122 122 122 122 122 122  64  40  40  40  40  40  40  40
 [847]  40  40  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  58  71  71  75  85 127  78
 [865]  78  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  15 152 152 152 152 337 337
 [883] 337 337 337 337 344 344 344 344 344 344 344  82  82  82  82  82  82  82
 [901]  82  82 348 348 348 348 348 348 348 348 348 351 351 351 359 359 355 355
 [919] 355 354 354 345 345 345 358 358 358 358 362 362 362 331 331 349 349 361
 [937] 361 378 364 364 364 369 369 369 375 375 375 373 373 373 373 342 365 365
 [955] 365 365 365 365 365 365 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379
 [973] 379 379 352 352 341 382 382 382 385 373 373 373 373 373 373 368 368 368
 [991] 389 389 389 389 285 285 285 308 308 309 309 321 322 326 329 329 329 329
 [1009] 330 330 330 330 385 385 385 385 385 385 385 380 380 380 380 380 380 380
 [1027] 386 386 386 386 390 390 390 390 365 365 393 393 393 393 393 393 393   393
```

[1045] 393 393 393 393 393 393 399 397 397 397 392 392 392 392 407 407 400 400
[1063] 413 413

Answer (score 3):

I founds out why R crashes when including the waves argument. GEEglm does not accept two observations on the same individual conducted on the same day. This makes sense when thinking through what the model does.  Hope this may help someone else.